# Adding Microsoft SQL Server 2008 JDBC Driver to Java project?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

Using Eclipse I tried this:
RIght click project -> build path -> add library -> connectivity driver definition -> new driver definition
-> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 JDBC Driver
and there it says:
 **Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: sqljdbc.jar.**

although I have sql driver placed in

- c:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\soapUI-Pro-4.0.1\bin\ext\sqljdbc.jar
- MyProject\|lib folder
- Java_Home\lib folder

WTH is needed to have this driver loaded correctly?
[image]

Comment: Which IDE are you using? The problem could be the spaces in your path (like "Program Files (x86)") but this is just a quick guess.

Comment: eclipse. btw when adding classpath do i need to put "" around path?

Comment: If it contains spaces, I would put it. I've had many similar problems.

Comment: OK but question is how do I add THAT driver ?

Comment: You need to specify the location of the driver jar on the JAR list tab.